# How to implement the following algorithm to sort a dynamic array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I was trying to write a simple sort function to sort int arrays, and I looked into some simple algorithms like bubble sort. I have written the following code, and it does an OK job to sort int arrays, in an ascending order:

```
void bubble_sort(float *scores, int size) {
    int i = 0,j = 0;
    float container = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
            if(scores[j] > scores[j + 1]) {
                container = scores[j];
                scores[j] = scores[j + 1];
                scores[j + 1] = container;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I thought of how I would usually sort a set of integers on a piece of paper, and I thought why not write a code that would do the same thing. But it turns out it is not as simple as I thought it would be at first glance.
I noticed that I usually use a simple algorithm to sort a set of integers in an ascending order, using the following method:

assume the set `{4, 8, 1, 9, 0}`

- **first I create an empty set** that has five empty places.
  `{ ,  ,  ,  ,  }`
- **I look for the minimum in the set,** which is 0 in this case.
- and then **I add it to the first empty place in my new set**:
  `{0,  ,  ,  ,  }`
- finally **I delete the element I used** from the original set:
  `{4, 8, 1, 9}`
- I repeat the above process until there are no more elements left in my original set.
- Now I have an ordered set.

So I went ahead and wrote a small function that can find the minimum in an array:

```
int minimum(int *array, int size) {
    int i, min = array[0];
    for(i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if(array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

I was going to write a function that would take an array and sort it, until I realized I can't delete items from an array. I’m at a loss here, what should I do next?

Comment: Copy the later elements of the array down one step, while remembering to change the size. If you "remove" the last element, just decrease the size.

Comment: The algorithm you invented is called selection sort. Usual thing to do is to just swap minimum with place where you want to put it.

Comment: c arrays are just bytes in memory, not objects, so you can not modify them simply

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a sorting algorithm called selection sort. Repeatedly select the minimum element and yield it. You don't have to perform a deletion, just maintain a index NEXT that tells you the next position to which you should write the number (initially set to 0).

So essentially you simulate a deletion of an item at position POS by swapping it with the number at position NEXT.

The naive implementation takes O(n*n) time because you go over the list to find the minimum. A faster selection algorithm would use a heap structure to get the minimum in O(lg n) time.